# Python3+Selenium, need to get value inside <td> that have <b> and <script> inside

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, text

Just as the title says, i'm trying to capture the value 999.999.999 inside this td tag. Have tried the following:

- td.text
- td.value
- script.value
- b.value
- execute_script("return sayMonto")
- execute_script("return sayMonto;")
- execute_script("return sayMonto()")
- execute_script("return sayMonto();")
- execute_script("sayMonto")
- execute_script("sayMonto()")
- execute_script("sayMonto();").

But no cigar. Here you have a snipet of the html, for security reasons this is the only i think i can show you. Every day that number changes, and need to copy and paste it, along with others, in the same site. It's pure madness, so please help me on this one. Have automated bots for other sites, but this one have proven to be hard to pull, for me at least.

```
<tr>
    <td style="boder-width:1px">
        <b>Irrelevant_text_that_i_capture_but_i_really_don´t</b>
       <!--&nbsp; 999.999.999-->
        <script language="javascript">
            sayMonto('999.999.999');
        </script>
       999.999.999
    </td>
   <!-- <td style="border-width:1px">&nbsp;&nbsp;999.999.999</td> -->
</tr>
```

PS: this is the error that is being thrown

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: cTexto is undefined`

I have never used that var, so it's must be from the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do that strictly with selenium. You'll have to use another library, maybe [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

For example:

```
# use selenium to get the html
html = driver.page_source

# pass it to beautifulsoup
td = soup.find("td")
# extract the elements you don't want
b = td.find("b")
b.extract()
sc = td.find("script")
sc.extract()
# print just the number
print td.text.strip()
```

Comment: Downloaded and installed Bs4. But i've tryed your code. But i just can't get to navigate to the element. I have never used bs4. Also started coding python like 2 month ago, so please be kind.

Comment: @dmb can you show the rest of the page source then? It's possible to select elements using a variety of methods, from css classes to other possible attributes of the particular element. But without seeing more of the source it's hard to show how for this example.

Comment: It's a banking site, so you can't accesses it without a password. I have other solution but it depends on the last info recieved and manage csv files in that case, but if i can grab that text it will more trustworthy. I will give it a look at css selectors and see what other info i can give you. I might be able to grab the specific javascript function and post it here.

Comment: @dmb I put together a little example of located the table within a page, grabbing data from a particular column and doing it for all table rows. [Check out the source](https://github.com/bmcculley/stackoverflow_questions/tree/master/35736910) hopefully that gets you on your way.

Comment: I'll give it a go when i get home. I gave it a rest over the weekend in hope that, that moment of clarity to come, but no cigar for me yet. I'm still working on this silly thing, so i will be updating.

Comment: Turned out, i was grabbing the wrong element the whole time. Even though i counted many times, and used the index number that it was supossed to be, selenium was grabbing another table. In some part of the route there was 4 tables, I needed to access the secon one, so index number [1], but the thing is it's grabbing the [0]. Anyway, thanks a lot messing with the thing i learned a little bit about exec_script, and a little bit of BS4. The solution was to get to the TD element and get text, that's it.